# How to load a pyspark dataframe into cosmos having different datatypes in a a single column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to load a pyspark dataframe into cosmos container. one of my column (rating) has values both in string and int.

| ID | rating |
| --- | --- |
| id1 | 5 |
| id2 | bad |

I want to load data into cosmos as per their data types. for example,
In pyspark I tried casting the datatypes based on the value, similar to this. I have tried different versions of the below, like checking the values with (rlike("^[0-9]+$")) etc.

```
df = df.withColumn("rating", when(col("rating").cast("int").isNotNull(), col("rating").cast("int")).otherwise(col("rating")))
```

But once I load the data into cosmos, it all come as string, with "" around the value, for example "5" and "bad". Instead what I want is , 5 and "bad".

I am not sure if related to cosmos config when write the data, so here's my setting

```
"spark.cosmos.write.strategy": "ItemOverwrite",
"spark.cosmos.serialization.inclusionMode" : "NonNull",
"spark.cosmos.write.bulk.enabled": "true",
"mode" : "Append",
"Upsert" : "true"
```

Comment: Not really clear what your issue is but... one thing is that you're mixing numbers and strings as your rating. Your dataframe, unlike a Cosmos DB container, will want a single data type for a column, not a mix. You probably need to rethink this.

Comment: As a workaround I had to convert the dataframe into json array. Then manipulating the json object by casting the datatypes. Then load into cosmos container, which propagate the correct types.